# How to refactor a code that could return 2 different types of object in Java

Tags: java, refactoring, option-type

So I have written a code that looks like this :

```
public ClassA myMethod(param1) {
    ClassB myObject;

    //START of code block #1
    try {
        myObject = tryToGetObject(param1);
        if (myObject == null) {
            return new ClassA("it's null");
        }
    } catch (ParamNotValidException e) {
        return new ClassA("param1 is not valid");
    }
    //END of code block #1

    /**
    Here do a lot of things with myObject
    */

    return new classA(myObject.toString());
}
```

The thing is, I have a lot of very similar code to `code block #1` and I would like to refactor all that. The problem is that this code block can either return :

- `myObject`, which I will use later to build a `ClassA` object to return

OR

- directly a `ClassA` object.

NB:

- `ClassB` id *not* a subclass of `ClassA`
- I used String as `ClassA` constructor parameters for the example but the real code is not using Strings.

I'd like to get something that *kind of* looks like this :

```
public ClassA method(param1) {
    ClassB myObject;

    //START of code block #1
    getMyObjectOrReturnClassAObject();
    //END of code block #1

    /**
    Here do a lot of things with myObject
    */

    return new classA(myObject.toString());
}
```

I tried to look into java `Optional` but i'm not sure if and how I could use this here.

*Some context to clarify* :
This code is about returning Java Play `Result`. For example when a user asks for a specific object using an exposed API, it performs some tests about the user's permissions, the validity of the request, and other things. If one test fails, It returns a `play.Result` with the appropriate HTTP.Status, error code, error message and so on. If each test passes, It returns a json representation of the requested object along with HTTP 200 status.

Comment: In the first block return `Optional.empty()`,. otherwise `Optional.of(myObject)`. Usage like: `method(a).ifPresent(my -> ...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already suggested going with `Optional`, which is a good direction here.

First of all, modify `tryToGetObject(param1)` to return `Optional<Object>` while using either `Optional.of()` or `Optional.ofNullable()`. Then you can do the following:

```
myObject = tryToGetObject(param1).orElse(new ClassA("it's null"));
```

You could wrap that in another method to get rid of the exception:

```
private Object getMyObjectOrReturnClassAObject(Object param1) {
    try {
        return tryToGetObject(param1).orElse(new ClassA("it's null"));
    catch(ParamNotValidException e) {
        return new ClassA("param1 is not valid");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i'm missing something here, since `tryToGetObject(param1)` will return a `ClassB` object , wouldn't the line `return tryToGetObject(param1).orElse(new ClassA("it's null"));` make the compilation fail ? because it seems to me this line could return either a `ClassB` object if `tryToGetObject()` works or a `ClassA` Object if it fails ?

Comment: @Tom Sorry, i have edited my answer, you would have to use `Object` as return type then or use another common superclass.

Comment: And then test the class of the returned Object ? I'm not sure I am happy with this, but I feel like you have given me plenty of leads to answer my problem, so thank you, this is an accepted answer !

Comment: @Tom I have realised that this may not be the best approach if ClassB is not a subclass of ClassA, can you clarify?

Comment: Indeed classB is not a subclass of classA, i will edit my question to specify this. This code is about returning Java Play `results`. For example when a user asks for a specific object using an exposed API, I perform some test about the user's permission, the validity of the request, and other thing. If one test fail, I return a `play.Result` with the appropriate HTTP.Status, error Code and so on. If every tests passes, I return a json representation of the requested object along with HTTP 200 status.